# When using a load balancer how do find out what ec2 instance you're accessing from the browser?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is there a way to determine the ip address of the ec2 instance you're accessing from the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only if your backend server identifies itself in the response. For instance, you might configure it to insert an HTTP header in the response.

Comment: A comment embedded in the HTML (or a tooltop on a logo) is often a convenient solution too -- the latter has the advantage of being something Joe Average User can do when you're troubleshooting something: "OK hover over the MyCompany logo and a little yellow box should appear - what does it say in the box?"